# How may I solve AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' for this problem?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
nodiscount_price = container.find("div",{"class":"discount_block tab_item_discount no_discount"})

if(nodiscount_price != None):
    nodiscount_price = nodiscount_price.text
```

nodiscount_price is a variable that may or may not have a value that is why I used an if() statement to prevent any error but when executed, it gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Are you sure it is this line? Please improve your question providing more infromation, so that we can reproduce your issue, exactly. How to create [mcve] Thanks --- Some more code, an url  or also the html would help to find a better solution and solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work:

```
if nodiscount_price is not None:
    nodiscount_price = nodiscount_price.text
else:
    nodiscount = 'empty'
```

But you can also handle it for example with `try & except` to avoid raising an error:

```
try:
    nodiscount_price = container.find("div",{"class":"discount_block tab_item_discount no_discount"}).get_text()
except:
    nodiscount_price = ''
```